# How i can compare a variable with a data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

```
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving Show

type Aluno = (Numero,Nome,Regime,Classificacao)
type Numero = Int
type Nome = String
data Regime = ORD | TE | MEL  deriving Show
data Classificacao = Aprov Int| Rep| Faltou deriving Show
type Turma = BTree Aluno
```

I have this functions that counts how many "Alunos" have Regime TE.

My code:

```
numeroT :: Eq  => Turma -> Int
numeroT Empty = 0
numeroT (Node (x,_,r,_) e d) = if (r==TE) then 1+((numeroT e)+(numeroT d))
                                      else (numeroT e)+(numeroT d)
```

Can I not compare `r` with TE? Getting `Eq` error.

Comment: In the future, please add the whole error message when you run into a problem like this. “`Eq` error” could be a lot of completely different things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My first Question though. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1) Allow Eq

```
data Regime = ORD | TE | MEL  deriving (Show,Eq)
```

2) Use pattern-matching instead:

```
case r of
  TE -> 1 + (numeroT e + numeroT d)
  _ -> numeroT e + numeroT d
```

A shorter version of (2) is

```
(case r of 
  TE -> (+1)
  _ -> id) $ numeroT e + numeroT d
```

Comment: @AlexandreMirra If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count. Once you’ve gathered 15 reputation points on this site, you will also be able to upvote answers.

Comment: Simpler, I think, to write `(case r of TE -> 1; _ -> 0) + ...`.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell does not automatically assume that newly-defined data types allow equality-comparison. For some types this just isn't possible: for instance, you can in general not decide whether two functions are equal.

For simple ADTs like `Regime` however, it is certainly possible. In doubt, you could define the `Eq` instance yourself:

```
instance Eq Regime where
  ORD==ORD = True
  TE==TE   = True
  MEL==MEL = True
  _ == _   = False
```

but to such a simple data type GHC can actually figure out alone how to do it: just add `Eq` to the `deriving` list.

```
data Regime = ORD | TE | MEL  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

**However**, in Haskell, equality comparison is generally avoided: it tends to be clumsy and sometimes inefficient. Much more elegant is when you can pattern-match on constructors as Tohava showed: this lets you deconstruct a data structure and simultaneously decide what to do with the contents.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just used: 

    instance Eq Regime where:

And my function just worked ;) . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [pattern matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) of Haskell you can create:

```
numeroT :: Turma -> Int
numeroT Empty = 0
numeroT (Node (x,_,TE,_) e d) = (numeroT e) + (numeroT d) + 1
numeroT (Node (x,_,_,_) e d)  = (numeroT e) + (numeroT d)
```